# how to group column as per its unique value and get count in to different column as per its value?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am having a Category table as follows,

[image: This is my table]

i want retrieve following results according to `scStatus`value and its count group by `catID`

```
catID | 0 | 2 | 3
----- |---|---|---
 2    | 1 | 0 | 1
 3    | 1 | 1 | 0
 4    | 2 | 0 | 1
 5    | 0 | 1 | 0
```

I tried this,`select catID,count(scStatus) as [Count] from tableName group by catID,scStatus order by catID` but i cant get into column that values.

`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a pivot query:

```
SELECT catID,
       SUM(CASE WHEN scStatus = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [0],
       SUM(CASE WHEN scStatus = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [2],
       SUM(CASE WHEN scStatus = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [3]
FROM Category
GROUP BY catID
```

Answer (score 1):

**pivot** operator

```
select      *
from        (select catID,scStatusvalue from t) t
                pivot (count(scStatusvalue) for scStatusvalue in ([0],[2],[3])) t
```